# How to append output file name using input file name without extention while using ghostscript?

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line, ghostscript

I'm using GS to "compress" PDF with 2 clicks. I've added a context menu in windows register with abovementioned code.

For instance if I use it on test.pdf the output file will be test.pdf-compressed.pdf. It works, but I would like to get rid of extention in the filename. Is there any way to do so?

I've tryied to use cmd arguments, but it does not seem to work with the postscript.

`C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin64c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sOutputFile=%1%-compressed.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f %1`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Ghostscript question. If you get the arguments correct then the parameters passed to Ghostscript will be correct and the output file will be what you want.

You haven't said what you've tried, so that makes it pretty hard to make suggestions. However you should be able to use %~dp1 and/or %~n1 instead of simply %1 to expand to just a path or file. There are other variations, typing "help for" at the Windows command line will give you more details.

Note as always that Ghostscript does not compress PDF files, by using `-dPDFSETTINSG=/ebook` you are producing a brand-new PDF file which has altered the content from the original (image will be downsampled for example).

Also the sequence `-c .setpdfwrite -f` has been redundant for years, you don't need it.

[EDIT]

This batch file demonstrates the use of the command shell variable expansion in a batch file

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Input file is %1
ECHO Input directory is %~dp1

\ghostpdl\debugbin\gswin32c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%~dp1\new.pdf %1
```

When saved as test.bat and then test d:\temp\input.ps the following output is generated:

```
Input file is d:\temp\input.ps
Input directory is d:\temp\
GPL Ghostscript GIT PRERELEASE 9.28 (2019-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
```

And a file new.pdf is created in the directory d:\temp

So the variable expansion works as expected, because it happens before the command line is executed.

If it still doesn't work for you, then you're going to have to provide more information. In your place I would start by removing the -dNOPAUSE and -dBATCH switches from the command line, at least that way you'll be able to see if Ghostscript is trying to tell you something.

Comment: ->You haven't said what you've tried [...]
"I've tried to use cmd arguments" that is to say %~dp1 etc. mentioned by you and it did not work.That's why I'm here.
I've tried ```-sOutputFile=%~dp1\test1.pdf``` just to see if it can take file path correctly. It did not work. Meanwhile it works when I'm just using | clip.
```sOutputFile=
->Note as always that Ghostscript does not compress PDF files
I know. That's why I've put the word compress into comas. But thanks anyways.

->Also the sequence -c .setpdfwrite -f has been redundant for years, you don't need it.
That is useful. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't actually say you'd tried %~dp1, you just said 'command arguments' whicih could mean pretty much anything. What do you mean by 'didn't work' ? Gort an error, produced a filename you didn'rt expect (if so what ?), something else ? I don't know what you mean when you say "I'm just using | clip".

Comment: When I try to use ```-sOutputFile=%~dp1\test1.pdf```  an empty command-line window would appear and immediatly close. No error messages, no files generated.

Also, I've did some research on sOutPutfile and it seems to require a specific argument type. That's why I think it's actually related to ghost script.

Comment: Well, I disagree wiht you. THe command expansion is done before the argument is passed to Ghostscript (or it is if you use a batch file). In order to use the shell expansion it must be, Ghostscript itself does not understand the Windows command shell variable expansion, as its a cross-platform application. I've amended my answer with a batch file to demonstrate what I mean. Note that by using -dNOPAUSE and -dBATCH its no surprise that a command window opens and closes. You've told Ghostscript not to pause between pages, and to exit on completion, so that's what it did.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've tried the following command after reading your example: ```gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%~dp1\new.pdf %1```
I've made sure to remove  -dNOPAUSE and -dBATCH. However  cmd window keeps closing immediately.

Comment: I'd suggest you write a batch file and attach that to your context menu, as a debugging aid. It sounds to me like its not running Ghostscript. You may need to put a fully qualified path to the binary in there. Have the batch file write out to a file what its doing and have it run Ghostscript. Beyond that, I don't really know, its not a Ghostscript problem really.

Comment: UPD: I have some new info. It seems that the problem is somehow related to gs. It seems to not recognize %~ operator. That is to say:
If I use: ```-sOutputFile="%1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%1"``` it works properly.
If I use: ```-sOutputFile="%1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%~1"``` it creates a blank 1-page PDF.
If I put "~" in the -sOutputFile after"%" like this: ```-sOutputFile="%~1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%~1"``` or ```-sOutputFile="%~dpn1-processed.pdf"``` it will not create any PDF and give this error message:
"Unabe to open the initial device, quitting".

Comment: The %~ is nothing to do with Ghostscript, and no, it certainly does not process it. The expansions you are using there are handled by the OS, not by Ghostscript. So if you use %~1 in a batch file (aka shell script, command script etc), the shell will expand that **before** passing on to Ghostscript. If you type a command line with %~1 in it, then Ghostscript will treat it literally. This is not a Ghostscript bug and is common to all command line programs in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've clearly stumbled upon this posting a bit late.
However, I wanted to post my answer in case someone comes looking for a solution to a similar issue, in the future.

I started by creating a new Folder on my Desktop, titled "PDF", in which I placed the "test.pdf" File.
I then created a .BAT File, titled "CompressPDF.bat", to which I added the Script below.

This Script will Loop through and Compress Any/All .PDF Files, that are placed in the "PDF" Folder.
It then correctly appends the "-compressed.pdf" string to the File Name, thereby saving the "test.pdf" File as "test-compressed.pdf", per the request of the OP.

As you will Notice, I have Added the "PAUSE" Command at the very end of the Script.
This will keep the Window from Automatically Closing until you Press Any Key, which will allow you to review any Errors that may have arisen, during the compression process.

```
@echo off
cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\PDF"
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    gswin64c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="%%~nf-compressed.pdf" "%%f"
)
PAUSE
```

I hope this post is able to help others, who may be looking for an answer to a similar issue.

Please, feel free to response or to reach out to me, if anyone has any questions, as I am always happy to help.